# Windows 8 app memory leak calling web service

Tags: web-services, windows-store-apps

We have an app which is pulling information from a SOAP web service.

The web service is called within a loop pulling down the items 30 at a time until it has retrieved all of the items required.

We have noticed that the memory usage for the app grows each time we make a call to the web service and is not released again.

I have added in code to make sure all objects are set back to null once finished and included gc.Collect()
gc.WaitForPendigFinalizers()
gc.Collect()
at the end of the loop to clean up memory waiting for garbage collection.

Has anyone come across any similar memory leaks in a Windows Store app?

Thanks

Comment: Are you disposing everything?

Comment: As far as I can see I am disposing of everything